# ng-attr not evaluating on directive element

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I am attempting to pass data from the controller to an isolated scope using element attributes. Here is my tag in the view:

```
<comment ng-attr-cid="{{question.id}}" ctype="questions"></div>
```

And here is the directive:

```js
'use strict'

angular.module('arlo.directives').directive "comment", ['Comment', (Comment) ->
  directive =
    templateUrl: "angular/partials/comment.html"
    restrict: "E"
    scope:
      cid: "="
      ctype: "="

    link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
      scope.toggled = false
      scope.comment = null
      scope.comments

      scope.toggle = ->
        if scope.toggled is true then scope.toggled = false else scope.toggled = true
        scope.comment = null

      scope.addComment = ->
        Comment.addComment(scope.ctype, scope.cid, scope.comment).then ->
          scope.comments = Comments.commentsList
          scope.toggled = false
          scope.comment = null

      scope.loadComments = ->
        Comment.loadComments(scope.ctype, scope.cid).then ->
          scope.comments = Comments.commentsList

      scope.loadComments()
]
```

The problem is cid is getting assigned "{{question.id}}" instead of the value of value of question.id.  I attempted to use ng-attr-cid="question.id" but that is not working either.  ON top of that, ctype is evaluating as undefined.

If I add ng-attr-cid on any other element, it evaluates and added cid="" to the element.

Can someone please explain what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an isolated scope (what you get when you specify a scope object on a directive) you can import variables into the scope based on attributes of the original element.

In this case, there is no need to use `ng-attr` since our directive will handle grabbing the values.

- `"="` is for when you want to copy a variable, so you just provide the variable name, e.g. `cid="question.id"`
- `"@"` is for when you want to interpolate a variable before passing it to your directive, e.g. `cid="{{question.id}}"`.  Also very handy for passing raw strings.

In short

- drop the `ng-attr`
- change the directive `scope.cid` to `"@"` *OR* use `cid="question.id"` in your HTML
- check the value of `questions` (not sure if this was deliberately pluralised or not, since `ctype` is undefined in your directive, it means that `questions` is undefined as well.

Here is a [plnkr showing the fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/ws2z8eUsMVy05BLmcnYw?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear why you need the ng-attr prefix on the cid attribute, but if you do in fact need to do that then unfortunately your 'cid' isolate scope value is interfering with some implementation detail of how angular deals with ng-attr-*.

You can awkwardly work around that by using a link function in your directive which observes the 'cid' attribute that will be created by ng-attr-cid, and removing your existing `cid: '='` property on your isolate scope definition.

```
... your existing directive definition ...
link: function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
  attrs.$observe('cid', function(val) {
    scope['cid'] = val;
  });
}
... etc, etc ...
```

This sets up an observer on the `cid` attribute and updates the scope whenever it changes.

[See plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/J6IuYB00UovPDWTEM5xC?p=preview)